# Specified query not executable here - pentaho reporting

Tags: pentaho

So I've designed a report in Pentaho Report Designer 3.9 and previewed it and ran it on my machine and everything works fine.

I have an input paramater that is a dropdown list and gets its values from a query called Vertical-List.

Now the drop down works on my machine. However, when I publish the report to the Online interface and try to access it, I get a message that says "The Specified query 'Vertical-List' is not executable here". I don't know what that means and what to do. It worked this morning and suddenly it stopped working.

Please help a brother out.

here is the query that generates the drop down

```
SELECT
     `verticals`.`vertical_id`,
     `verticals`.`vertical_name`
FROM
     `verticals`
```

Comment: By online interface, do you mean the BI Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your datasource and query, especially the parameters. If you have parameters, remember that a parameter is read in the Pentaho Report Designer as `${parameter_name}`.

Also double check that you have defined the datasource in your BI Server.

Comment: I think i've done that.. will double check thank you. Also ever since i updated my PRD to 3.9 my old reports take for ever to load

Comment: Hmm, I think reports take a while to load, but not forever though

Comment: I verified all my datasources and queries and the parameters are correct.. the report runs fine on desktop but when its published i get the error. do i need to restart anything?

Comment: Have you defined the datasource in your BI server?

Comment: Yes I have.  I'm looking at it now.. and i have the tables in there too

Comment: I was able to replicate it on my desktop by removing the query that generates the drop down and this is what i got..   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Failed: The specified query 'Vertical-List' is not executable here.

Comment: Hmm, but are you sure your query is working using your SQL client?

Comment: yes.. i've checked all my queries through my client.. i'll double check them again and its just with that specific query.. Also now when i publish new reports nothing shows up in BI servers when the report is genrated..i'm running out of solutions to think of

Comment: The problem lies within that query then, try to optimize it more, better even, edit your question above, and show the query there

Comment: i updated the question, the query is very simple.. which makes me thing something maybe be wrong somewhere else

Comment: Is that the only query you have for parameters? Try removing other queries, and then leave that only. Isolate the case.

Comment: yes thats the only query as far as input parameters.. the other 2 are just date params.  I created a report just with that query as a parameter and it still fails.. btw. thank you for your continuous help..

Comment: No prob dude, if your query is exactly as stated above in your question, maybe you're missing a closing ' (single quote) at the end?

Comment: thats not the case.. it was actually i typo of me typing it here.  from what i read it may be a Jfreereport error.  I've checked all my data sources on admin pannel, bi server, and my prd and they are all the same.

Comment: hey man thanks for u help.. i ended up reinstalling bi-server and reverted everything back to 3.8 in prd.. it looks like that when i moved my reports written in 3.8 to 3.9 it messed things up

Comment: Me too suffering with exact issue. 
I have designed a report in Report designer 3.6 and my Bi-server version is 3.6. me too having a date parameter and a drop down value and it works good in preview mode but says the following error 'The SQL statement is not executable here' after publishing.

I have tried Biserver 4.5 and the dropdown works fine but the date parameter shows Jan 1, 1970 default. and default value formula also not working for that date parameter.